# Discord.JS getting message author from awaitMessages & checking the message content

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm using Discord.JS's `awaitMessages` to check if a message is either a **1, 2, 3, 4 or C**.

I want to be able to check if the author of the **1, 2 ect.** is the same author as the one who initiated the `awaitMessages`.
For example, if someone initiated the `awaitMessages` and typed out a **1**, how would I get the author of that '1' message?

```
msg.channel.awaitMessages(mess => mess.content === '1', {
    max: 1,
    time: 10000,
    errors: ['time'],
 }).then((gotMess) => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (gotMess.author == msg.author && gotMess.first().content == '1') {
            resolve(queueVideo(msg, queue, 0));
        } else if (gotMess.first().content !== '1') {
            return reject();
        }
    });
}).catch((e => console.error(e));
```

That is the code I'm using

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Discord.JS's `.map()` was the answer!